# Erro ao Percorrer um Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Boa tarde pessoal,
estou com uma duvida em relação a json,

eu tenho o seguinte json :

```
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "result":{
    "nr":26,
    "lista":[
      {
        "codigo":"2",
        "nome":"Pratos Quentes"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"3",
        "nome":"Sobremesas"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"4",
        "nome":"Bebidas Nao Alcoolicas"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"7",
        "nome":"Cocktails"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"10",
        "nome":"Cafes"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"11",
        "nome":"Consummes"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"12",
        "nome":"Porções"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"13",
        "nome":"Chocolates"
      }
    ]
  },
  "id":138827
}
```

e ao tentar percorrer a lista de produtos , só carrega apenas o ultimo produto este é o código que estou utilizando para percorrer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var caminho = "http://brunofejesus.pe.hu/categorias.json";
     $.getJSON(caminho, function(data) {

         for(i in data.result.lista){
            $('#gridCategorias').html(data.result.lista[i].nome);
         }
     });
  </script>
```

aqui um print :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você tem que concatenar o html:

```
var html = '';
$.getJSON(caminho, function(data) {

     for(i in data.result.lista){
        html += '<p>'+data.result.lista[i].nome+'</p>';
     }
     $('#gridCategorias').html(html);
 });
```

ou então transformar seu array em string:

```
$('#gridCategorias').html(data.result.lista.toString()); // mas vai vir com vírgulas entre os dados
```

Comment: Obrigado Douglas pela ajuda ! funcionou vlw